# linq nested query

Tags: linq

I have a query that has the following

```
 var myvar = from table in MyDataModel
             where.....
             select new MyModel
             {
                  modelvar1 = ...,
                  modelvar2 = (from..... into anothervar)
             }
```

What I want to do is have modelvar2 be a join between the result I currently get from anothervar with another table in MyDataModel.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be more specific? Why isn't it working now?

Comment: it's not working because I'm missing the part that comes after the parenthesis to calculate the join. I'm stuggling on it at the moment but if you can show me the syntax, that'd be awesome.

Answer (score 2):

The parenthesis looks more like a subquery than a join. This is how you do a join.
Example tables from the [AdventureWorks database](http://msftdbprodsamples.codeplex.com/).

```
using (DataClasses1DataContext context = new DataClasses1DataContext())
{
    // If you have foreign keys correctly in your database you can
    // join implicitly with the "dot" notation.
    var myvar = from prod in context.Products
                where prod.ListPrice < 10
                select new
                {
                    Name = prod.Name,
                    Category = prod.ProductSubcategory.ProductCategory.Name,
                };

    // If you don't have foreign keys you need to express the join
    // explicitly like this
    var myvar2 = from prod in context.Products
                join prodSubCategory in context.ProductSubcategories
                on prod.ProductSubcategoryID equals prodSubCategory.ProductSubcategoryID
                join prodCategory in context.ProductCategories
                on prodSubCategory.ProductCategoryID equals prodCategory.ProductCategoryID
                where prod.ListPrice < 10
                select new
                {
                    Name = prod.Name,
                    Category = prodCategory.Name,
                };

    // If you REALLY want to do a subquery, this is how to do that
    var myvar3 = from prod in context.Products
                 where prod.ListPrice < 10
                 select new
                 {
                     Name = prod.Name,
                     Category = (from prodSubCategory in context.ProductSubcategories
                                 join prodCategory in context.ProductCategories
                                 on prodSubCategory.ProductCategoryID equals prodCategory.ProductCategoryID
                                 select prodCategory.Name).First(),
                 };

    // If you want to get a list from the subquery you can do like this
    var myvar4 = from prodCategory in context.ProductCategories
                select new
                {
                    Name = prodCategory.Name,
                    Subcategoreis = (from prodSubCategory in context.ProductSubcategories
                                    where prodSubCategory.ProductCategoryID == prodCategory.ProductCategoryID
                                    select new { prodSubCategory.ProductSubcategoryID, prodSubCategory.Name }).ToList(),
                };

}
```

Comment: Thanks. What I really want is a subquery, like example 3. Instead of taking the First element like you showed, I want to join the result of the subquery with another table. How does that work?

Comment: @user471807, I added a fourth example where a list is returned from the subquery. Beware, this can sometimes create overly expensive SQL queries if you nest it too deep, monitor them in SQL Profiler to be sure you get a sane query.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT [t0].[OrderID], [t0].[CustomerID], [t0].[EmployeeID], [t0].[OrderDate], [t0].[RequiredDate], [t0].[ShippedDate], [t0].[ShipVia], [t0].[Freight], [t0].[ShipName], [t0].[ShipAddress], [t0].[ShipCity], [t0].[ShipRegion], [t0].[ShipPostalCode], [t0].[ShipCountry]
FROM [Orders] AS [t0]
INNER JOIN ([Order Details] AS [t1]
    INNER JOIN [Products] AS [t2] ON [t1].[ProductID] = [t2].[ProductID]) ON [t0].[OrderID] = [t1].[OrderID]
```

can be write as

```
from o in Orders
join od in (
    from od in OrderDetails join p in Products on od.ProductID equals p.ProductID select od) 
    on o.OrderID equals od.OrderID
select o
```